# ember data, how do I get the api I'm working with to work without hacking everything

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is ember data 1.13.9 and newer.....

Here's my problem. My server will send responses that look like this (truncated for brevity):

```
{"response": 
       {"status": "ok", 
       "errors": false, 
       "warnings": false, 
       "recordcount": 44, 
       "err_msg": "", 
       "results": [
         {"city": "Rock Hill", 
         "zipcode": "111", 
         "storetaxondelivery": null, 
         "storetaxonpickup": null, 
         "stateid": "SC"}, 
         {"city": "MILLERTON", 
         "zipcode": "12546", 
         "storetaxondelivery": null, 
         "storetaxonpickup": null, 
         "stateid": "NY"}, 
       ], 
       "limit": 100,
        "offset": 0}
     }
```

The whole of serializers and adapters seem to make a primary assumption that just doesn't hold in my case...which is that the model name is somehow in the JSON response...for the API I'm working with, the resource type is inferred from the URI (i.e. server/zipcode/query in this case).

I realize that I can probably solve this by creating model-specific serializers and overriding modelNameFromPayloadKey or something, but that shouldn't be necessary. Maybe I'm missing where to accomplish this but apparently normalizeResponse is too late. Help?

Comment: I think you are going to end up with custom serializers or rolling without ember-data.

Comment: grrrr. if more context was passed into all the hooks I wouldn't need to... that's disappointing if true

Comment: Just write the custom serializer. It's not too hard. Override the normalize hook, set a breakpoint in Chrome debugger and munge the hash until it looks right. The whole process can be over quickly